# angular post is sending null value to server

Tags: angularjs, struts2

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.submitForm = function(cl) {
    console.log(cl);
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: "updated-profile",
      data: {
        cl: cl
      },
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      console.log("updated successfully");
      $scope.success = "Updated successfully";
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log("not updated");
      $scope.error = "Unable to update";
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="cl in clientList">
    <div id="error-messages" ng-show="error">{{error}}</div>
    <div id="success" ng-show="success">{{success}}</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="fname">First Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="cl.fname" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8">
        <input type="text " class="form-control" ng-model="cl.lname" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
      <label for="submit" class="sr-only">Update</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8">
      <input type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="update" ng-click="submitForm(cl)" name="Update" value="Update" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using above code to send data to server.
My server code is

```
public class Update extends ActionSupport {

    private Client cl = new Client();
    private String fname;
     public String update() {
        System.out.println("testing this");
        System.out.println("client detail " + cl.getFname() + " " + 
                             cl.getLname());
        System.out.println("fname"+getFname());
  }
}
```

I am getting

```
client detail null null 
fnamenull
```

If I am using       `data: {fname: cl.fname},` then also  `fnamenull`.
I am unable to pass any value using angular post to action.
What is wrong here?
What changes to made here to work it properly?

Comment: angularjs is deprecated

Comment: How angular js is depricated??

Comment: The version of angularjs you use is outdated.

Comment: It may be outdated but new for mee.

Answer (score 0):

Your button

```
<input type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="update" ng-click="submitForm(cl)" name="Update" value="Update" />
```

has to be inside the `ng-repeat` loop, otherwise it will not have access to the `cl` object as that is local to the `ng-repeat` scope.

Alternatively, if you want the button to be "global", you can submit the entire `clientList` in the `ng-submit` and then loop through the array inside your controller. It depends on your flow and what kind of UX/UI you need for the project.

Comment: Yes submit button in inside the ng-repeat

Comment: The code you submitted in your original code does not have the button inside ``ng-repeat``. Please check the template again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: "www.mylocalhost.com/api/updated-profile",
  data: {
    cl: cl
  },
});
```

When you are calling a $http service "url" parameter shoul contain a proper api path. just use a valid api url . I hope it will work.

Or 
change "cl":$scope.clientList